# Windows 10 Desktop Background as Lock Screen Image Automatically

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, desktop-customization, lock-screen

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to automatically set the lock screen background of Windows 10 to whatever the current desktop wallpaper is, automatically, via a script (not an app, at least not a UWP one). A script that can set the lockscreen image to specified image file is also acceptable.

The script can be in any supported scripting language for Windows, Powershell being preferred.

I was trying to do this myself using Powershell, but setting the relevant values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen\Creative` only changes the preview in Settings → Personalization → Lock Screen, not the actual lock screen itself.

I also looked into using Group Policy, but it does not feel like it does what I want (for one, it is on a per-machine basis, not per-user. I need it to be per-user). Also, the relevant GPO setting here is *Computer configuration → Administrative Templates & rarr; Control Panel → Personalization → Force a specific default lockscreen and logon image*, which is restricted only to the Enterprise, Education & Server SKUs. I want this to be usable for ideally all SKUs of Windows 10, not just the higher-end ones (I'm personally on Pro, so the above setting has no effect for me).

I guess what I'm looking for is the scripting equivalent of setting the lockscreen type to "Picture" and setting it to the relevant image path from the Settings app's lockscreen page (`ms-settings:lockscreen`) (which I have successfully obtained via the registry).